# SQL Query (Display All 'x' Where 'x' Is Not In Table '2' for field 'y' and has 'z' flag)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to return all 'contacts' that do not appear in the 'delegate' table for 'event name' but do have flags in the 'contacts' table that can selected by the user for the search.

I know the query can be broken in to 2 parts.

1. Are they already attending this event (Does their email appear in 'delegates' table with delegates.event field matching 'event' on the user form)

```
WHERE (
  d.Event <> [Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_EventName]
```

2. Do they match the criteria (Have they got the HR flag in 'contacts' table)

```
  AND (c.[HR-DEL]   = [Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_HRD]   OR IsNull([Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_HRD]));
```

Based on the 2 things that the query is required to do I have written the following code...

```
SELECT 
c.[First Name], c.[Last Name], c.Email, d.Event, c.Suppress, c.[HR-DEL]

FROM tbl_Contacts AS c LEFT JOIN tbl_Delegates AS d ON c.Email = d.Email

WHERE (
  d.Event <> [Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_EventName]
  And 
  c.Suppress = False
) 
  AND (c.[HR-DEL]   = [Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_HRD]   OR IsNull([Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_HRD]));
```

[FCC_HRD] refers to the user selected input on the form, I tried to use a <> to remove matching records but I feel this is where the compile error is so I changed these to and/or statements and this part now returns results with the matching flags (Success)

Other issue with attempting to do it this way is even if it worked it would remove anyone who was listed in the delegates/sponsor table. Which is why I added the <> statement for the Event as it only needs to remove them off the list for the named event. Again this works perfectly well (Success)

Final issue is the results are clearly being pulled from the 'delegates' table not the 'contacts' table as both parts above work but only display the results that match criteria in delegates table not from contacts.

[Here is the query/table relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJsPA.jpg)

[Here is the user form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YOXB.jpg) (This is not the final design)

Below are the 3 tables that are used in the query (2 direct, 1 linked)
Contacts (c)

```
+----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+----------+
| ID | First Name |   Last Name   |          Email          | HR-DEL | Suppress |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | A          | Platt         | a.platt@fake.com        | TRUE   | TRUE     |
|  2 | D          | Farr          | d.farr@fake.com         | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  3 | Y          | Helle         | y.helle@fake.com        | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  4 | S          | Oliphant      | soliphant@fake.com      | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  5 | J          | Bedell-Pearce | jbedell-pearce@fake.com | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  6 | J          | Walker        | j.walker@fake.com       | FALSE  | FALSE    |
|  7 | S          | Rug           | s.rug@fake.com          | FALSE  | FALSE    |
|  8 | D          | Brown         | d.brown@fake.com        | FALSE  | FALSE    |
|  9 | R          | Cooper        | r.cooper@fake.com       | TRUE   | FALSE    |
| 10 | M          | Morrall       | m.morrall@fake.com      | TRUE   | FALSE    |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+----------+
```

Delegates (d)

```
+----+-------------------------+-------+
| ID |          Email          | Event |
+----+-------------------------+-------+
|  1 | a.platt@fake.com        |     2 |
|  2 | d.farr@fake.com         |     1 |
|  3 | y.helle@fake.com        |     4 |
|  4 | soliphant@fake.com      |     3 |
|  6 | jbedell-pearce@fake.com |     2 |
+----+-------------------------+-------+
```

Events (not direct but used to check event name drop-down on user form vs event number in delegates)

```
+----+------------+
| ID | Event Name |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Test 1     |
|  2 | Test 2     |
|  3 | Test 3     |
|  4 | Test 4     |
+----+------------+
```

Based on form selection and this sample data I need to return the following:

All contacts who are flagged 'HR' TRUE, not suppressed or going to event named 'test 2' (Should be 5 - I always return the names of 'delegates' not going to the event only = 3)

Final results should be:

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+----------+
| ID | First Name | Last Name |       Email        | HR-DEL | Suppress |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|  2 | D          | Farr      | d.farr@fake.com    | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  3 | Y          | Helle     | y.helle@fake.com   | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  4 | S          | Oliphant  | soliphant@fake.com | TRUE   | FALSE    |
|  9 | R          | Cooper    | r.cooper@fake.com  | TRUE   | FALSE    |
| 10 | M          | Morrall   | m.morrall@fake.com | TRUE   | FALSE    |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+----------+
```

At the moment it appears to be pulling results from the wrong table (d not c). I attempted to change to OUTER join type but that returned with a FROM syntax error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you (a) break this down to a minimal example, see [mcve], (b)  [provide](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data for all source tables and the expected result (is this the list at the beginning of your post? It's not clear.)

Comment: In SQL you don't use `WHERE IsNull([foo])` but `WHERE [foo] IS NULL`.

Comment: Hi Andre, Let me work on updating the question again to be more understandable, the expected result is the list at the start. Due to the nature/content of the tables I can't share source data (GDPR) but could share table field heading if that would help

Comment: Sample data != real data. Include only the relevant columns.

Comment: Added sample data with only relevant columns. Basically if you run the query for the 'test' event on this data with only the 'HR' flag ticked it should return 5 contacts (ID: 2,3,4,9,10)

Comment: Sorry if I'm starting to sound obnoxious. But please use [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to add the data to your question (not via Gdrive link). There are still too many columns. Remove everything from the data and your SQL attempt that has no relevance to making the query work. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Not sounding obnoxious at all, I'm new to SQL and as such posting here when the more complex queries I attempt to code don't work. Guess there's a fine line between providing enough and too much information. anyway I've updated again and removed pretty much most of the columns for the test purposes as i can write them back in easily after

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, basically you want to do this:

```
SELECT A.foo
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B 
    ON A.bar = B.bar
WHERE
  <complex condition, partly involving B>
```

This cannot work. By including B in the global WHERE condition, you turn the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN, and so you will only ever get records that match between A and B.

You can either move the filter on B into the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT A.foo
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B 
    ON (A.bar = B.bar)
    AND (B.bamboozle = 42)
WHERE
  A.columns = things
```

or LEFT JOIN a filtered subquery:

```
SELECT A.foo
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT bar, columns FROM B 
     WHERE B.bamboozle = 42) AS B1
    ON A.bar = B1.bar
WHERE
  A.columns = things
```

So in your query, this is the *bamboozle* part you will need to move:

```
d.Event <> [Forms]![usf_FindCampaignContacts]![FCC_EventName]
```

Comment: Did this help? @Castiel